# Can't create ArmeriaCatsBackend in IOApp with Cats effects?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, armeria, sttp

I want to use `ArmeriaCatsBackend` as sttp backend with Cats effects.

The following code does not compile:

```
object Main extends IOApp {
  val backend = ArmeriaCatsBackend[IO]()
  // ...
}
```

> could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type cats.effect.kernel.Async[cats.effect.IO]
> Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.

[Documentation](https://sttp.softwaremill.com/en/latest/backends/catseffect.html)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dang. I was using scala-effects v2.x and sttp-ameria for v3.

After upgrading to scala-effects v3.x everything is ok.